# What is the best practice to use ENV vars with translations i18n from yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, yaml, rails-i18n

I have a very long text in yml, it's supossed to have a link somewhere in the middle. I wish to be able to change the link (from my env file), but doesn't seem right to parse `ENV['link']` in the yml. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Passing variables to translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations):

> ```
> # app/views/home/index.html.erb
> <%=t 'greet_username', user: "Bill", message: "Goodbye" %>
>
> # config/locales/en.yml
> en:
>   greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
> ```